# Binary Tree - Method to recursively count the number of nodes on a level without a count parameter (Java)

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I'm looking to take some code I've written in Java for a binary tree class and remove the count parameter from the arguments, but keep the whole thing recursive.

So, given a class with these variables:

```
 public class BinaryTree<E> {

  protected E data;
  protected BinaryTree<E> left,right;
```

How could I do that for:

```
public int levelCount(int count, int level){
 if (data == null) {return 0;}
 if (count == level) {return 1;}
 else {
  return this.getRight().levelCount(count+1,level) + this.getLeft().levelCount(count+1,level);
  } 
}
```

This should (and does) return the number of nodes at any given level of the binary tree.

So with a tree "thatTree" which looks like:

```
     2
   /    \
  6      3
 / \    / \
4   5  7   10
```

thatTree.levelCount(0) returns 1, thatTree.levelCount(1) returns 2, thatTree.levelCount(2) returns 4

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: Note that this isn't a site for providing "general critiques".

Comment: Please give an example of how this might be called & what it would return; it isn't clear what you are trying to compute here.

Comment: @ScottHunter The question is basically language-agnostic, and he's apparently trying to count how many nodes exist at a particular depth within the tree. Actually, he's already done that, but is asking if it can be done without the `count` parameter.

Comment: @ooga: If you expect someone to write code, the least you can do is specify the language.  And if you explain what you are trying to do, who knows, you might just solve your own problem.

Comment: "_thatTree.levelCount(0) returns 1, thatTree.levelCount(1) returns 2, thatTree.levelCount(2) returns 4_" ...??? You answered the logic of what you're looking for yourself. You don't even need recursion. If I understand well, what I quoted is very different from what you initially asked..

Answer (score 1):

Why not pass a single argument, subtract 1 on each recursion, and end when it is 0? Something like:

```
public int levelCount(int level){
  if (data == null || level < 1) {return 0;}
  if (level == 1) {return 1;}
  else {
    return this.getRight().levelCount(level-1) + this.getLeft().levelCount(level-1);
  } 
}
```